# How to capture screenshot of specified website?

Tags: screen-scraping, screenshot, capture

I want to know technique to capture screenshot if I have a url list of those sites like [google fastflip](http://fastflip.googlelabs.com/). What technology or techniques require for this kind of task. If this technique available in rails it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a HTML [rendering engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_layout_engines) for that.
The easy way is to use a browser plugin for that task.

Check out this: [15 Ways To Create Website Screenshots](http://mashable.com/2007/08/24/web-screenshots/)

Answer (score 1):

Hey, i'm using a headless webbrowser and Xvfb. First, install the package dependencies for example Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb imagemagick x11-apps
```

Then run the shellcript below using sudo to some "nobody user", like this:

```
/usr/bin/sudo -u nobody /path/screengrab.sh www.ibm.com 34344 >>/tmp/screengrab.log 2>&1
```

You might need to adjust the cropping etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf /home/nobody/.mozilla/

XAUTHORITY=

Xvfb :$2 -pixdepths 32 -screen 0 1024x1024x24 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
XPID=$!

sleep 1

firefox -width 2000 -height 1024 --display :$2 http://$1 &
FPID=$!

sleep 6
xwd -display :$2 -root -out /tmp/$2-$$.xwd

convert /tmp/$2-$$.xwd /u0/screengrabs/$1.png # Cache
convert -resize 300x300 /tmp/$2.xwd /tmp/$2-$$.png
convert -crop 287x248+0+29 /tmp/${2}-$$.png /tmp/${2}2-$$.png

mkdir -p /home/je/www/domaintool.se/docs/images/$1
cp /tmp/${2}2-$$.png /home/je/www/domaintool.se/docs/images/$1/`date +%Y%m%d`.png
rm -f /tmp/$2-$$.png /tmp/$2-$$.xwd /tmp/${2}2-$$.png

kill $XPID >/dev/null 2>&1
kill $FPID >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this excellent Firefox plugin Grab Them All https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7800/ which is a version of the author's also excellent Screengrab add on.

Grab them All allows you to point the browser at a list of URLs and then will produce all the screenshots for you in a specified directory. It works brilliant with most websites.

However I am trying to generate screenshots of Google Maps URLS which is not working for me at the moment because the pages are not standard pages - they use frames etc. But for most purposes the above is great - super quick and easy to set up. Hope that helps.